# Class with static members vs singleton

Tags: c++, design-patterns, static, singleton, monostate

Isn’t a class with only static members a kind of singleton design pattern? Is there any disadvantage of having such a class? A detailed explanation would help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This kind of class is known as a [monostate](http://jeremyjarrell.com/archive/2008/04/21/88.aspx) - it is somewhat different from a singleton.

Why use a monostate rather than a singleton? In their [original paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=331120.331154&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=9560984&CFTOKEN=28610657) on the pattern, Bell & Crawford suggest three reasonns (paraphrased by me):

- More natural access syntax
- singleton lacks a name
- easier to inherit from

I must admit, I don't find any of these particularly compelling. On the other hand, the monostate is definitely no *worse* than the singleton.

Comment: Different yes, but doesn't it achieve exactly the same thing?  I can't see how this has any advantages or disadvantages over the "traditional" singleton, in C++ at least.

Comment: There is the difference that space will not be allocated for a singleton unless it is used, but in practice a singleton object that is never used seems like a rare case. Does anyone have a common use-case where this would be important?

Comment: I also tend to think that the lazy-construction feature of typical singletons is useless in most cases -- those where we just need a global variable. However, in library case, we may need an on-the-fly construction in order to simplify the end-user's (developer actually) code.

Comment: First link is broken. Perhaps update with this one? http://wiki.c2.com/?MonostatePattern

Answer (score 15):

Robert C. Martin wrote an [article](http://objectmentor.com/resources/articles/SingletonAndMonostate.pdf) some times ago about the differences between the mono state pattern and the singleton pattern.

Comment: Based on the article, the only material differences that I could see were that in Java, destruction of a Monostate is guaranteed but it cannot be passed between JVMs -- are there any differences relevant to C++?

Comment: It's exactly the same as with other variables. If it is dynamically allocated, it should be deallocated with a compatible deallocator. If it is in the static storage (see GOTW/XC++, IIRC), it will be destroyed and the end of the program, but there is no way to implement dependencies.

Comment: Regarding the dependencies aspect, A.Alexandrescu's loki (from MC++D) singletons, and ACE singletons permit to specify dependencies. BTW, they are both non intrusive singletons.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a family of Logging classes.  They all implement "LogMessage(message, file, line_number).  Some send messages to stderr, some send email to a set of developers, some increment the count of the particular message in a message-frequency table, some route to /dev/null.  At runtime, the program checks its argument vector, registry, or environment variables for which Logging technique to use and instantiates the Logging Singleton with an object from a suitable class, possibly loading an end-user-supplied DLL to do so.  That functionality is tough to duplicate with a pure static Singleton.

Answer (score 1):

For a singleton all constructors have to be private, so that you can access only through a function. But you're pretty close to it.

Comment: If you really think that you should read about singletons again. Private constructors and one or more static members only accessilbe through a public member function is the very definition of a singleton

Comment: If this answer is so wrong that it deserves 5 downvotes, could you leave a comment why? Something like 'wrong wrong wrong' is not helpful and I'm still not convinced that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> class with all static members/methods
>   a kind of singleton design pattern

Class - not pattern. When we talk about classes we can say class **implements** pattern.

---

Static functions - is not member functions, they are similar on global functions. Maybe you don't need any class?

Quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

> In software engineering, the singleton
>   pattern is a design pattern that is
>   used to restrict instantiation of a
>   class to one object.

By this definition your implementation is not singleton implementation - you don't use common idea ***One (or several in extended definition) instance of class***.

But sometimes (not always) usage of class with all static functions and singleton pattern - not have meaningful difference.