# Why use a singleton instead of static methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I have never found good answers to these simple questions about helper/utility classes:

- Why would I create a singleton (stateless) instead of using static methods?
- Why would an object instance be needed if an object has no state?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720744/static-class-and-singleton

Comment: Don't think since we talk about 2 different langages so the answer may vary, but thanks for the link, in java never heard the term "monostate"

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Often, singletons are used to introduce some kind of *global state* to an application. (More often than really necessary, to be honest, but that's a topic for another time.)

However, there are a few corner cases where even a *stateless* singleton can be useful:

- You expect to extend it with state in the foreseeable future.
- You need an *object instance* for some particular *technical* reason.
   Example: Synchonization objects for the C# `lock` or the Java `synchronized` statement.
- You need inheritance, i.e., you want to be able to easily replace your singleton with another one using the same interface but a different implementation.
  Example: The `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` method in Java will return a singleton whose exact type is system dependent.
- You want *reference equality* for a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).
  Example: `DBNull.Value` in C#.

Comment: I'm gonna go with +1, although IMHO singletons are **misused** to introduce global states. The purpose of a singleton is not to make an object globally available, but to enforce that an object is instantiated only once. Global objects are a necessary evil. Unless really required, one should try not to use them, since they generally lead to high coupling, with SomeSingleton.getInstance().someMethod() all over the place. :)

Comment: It can be useful in games where you want only one render instance instead of multiple render instances, or with a network piping class where you set up an secure channel that there can be only one connection at a time.

Comment: "easily replace your singleton" part is the most important point in my point of view. Rest is pretty close to static class implementation.

Comment: Singletons are useful non-Null sentinel values for sum/product types and similar.  For example, being the None/Nothing value in an Option type or the Empty value for a collection type.  You get fast None/Empty testing as a bonus, because reference equality is all that's needed.

Comment: @itsbruce: Your examples aren't *singletons*: The empty list is not the only possible instance of the List class, and the None value is not the only possible instance of the Option class. However, there are example where sentinel value *are* singletons, and I have taken the liberty to add one to my answer. Thanks for the innput!

Comment: Only Inheritance sounds fair point to me

Answer (score 43):

I could see a case for a stateless singleton being used instead of a static methods class, namely for [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

If you have a helper class of utility functions that you're using directly, it creates a hidden dependency; you have no control over who can use it, or where. Injecting that same helper class via a stateless singleton instance lets you control where and how it's being used, and replace it / mock it / etc. when you need to.

Making it a singleton instance simply ensures that you're not allocating any more objects of the type than necessary (since you only ever need one).

Comment: *"you have no control over who can use it, or where."* Why would somebody need it?

Comment: @hagrawal for testing purpose, you should be able to mock it

Answer (score 19):

Actually i've found another answer not mentionned here: static methods are harder to test.

It seems most test frameworks work great for mocking instance methods but many of them no not handle in a decent way the mock of static methods.

Comment: But Powermock seems to be able to do so

Comment: It depends how you are calling the singleton. If you are calling it like `MyClass.INSTANCE.callMethod()` then it's just as untestable as statics. But if you're injecting the instance (even though it's a singleton instance and therefore always the same value will be injected) it's much easier to mock.

Answer (score 7):

In most programming languages classes elude a lot of the type system. While a class, with its static methods and variables is an object, it very often cannot implement an interface or extend other classes. For that reason, it cannot be used in a polymorphic manner, since it cannot be the subtype of another type. For example, if you have an interface `IFooable`, that is required by several method signatures of other classes, the class object `StaticFoo` cannot be used in place of `IFooable`, whereas `FooSingleton.getInstance()` can (assuming, `FooSingleton` implements `IFooable`).

Please note, that, as I commented on Heinzi's answer, a singleton is a pattern to control instantiation. It replaces `new Class()` with `Class.getInstance()`, which gives the author of `Class` more control over instances, which he can use to prevent the creation of unneccessary instances. The singleton is just a very special case of the factory pattern and should be treated as such. Common use makes it rather the special case of global registries, which often ends up bad, because global registries should not be used just willy-nilly.

If you plan to provide global helper functions, then static methods will work just fine. The class will not act as class, but rather just as a namespace. I suggest, you preserve high cohesion, or you might end up with weirdest coupling issues.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 4):

There is a trade-off between using which one. Singletons may or may not have state and they refer to objects. If they are  not keeping state and only used for global access, then static is better as these methods will be faster. But if you want to utilize objects and OOP concepts (Inheritance polymorphism), then singleton is better.

Consider an example: java.lang.Runtime is a singleton class in java. This class allows different implementations for each JVM. The implementation is single per JVM. If this class would have been static, we cannot pass different implementations based on JVM.

I found this link really helpful: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/03/difference-between-singleton-pattern-vs-static-class-java.html?

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This answer is good for including a concrete example in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

Singleton is not stateless, it holds the global state.

Some reasons which I can think of using Singleton are:

- To avoid memory leaks
- To provide the same state for all modules in an application e.g database connection

Comment: I know but actually a singleton can more or less be stateless... If it doesn't share any class attribute...

Answer (score 2):

For me **"Want Object State use Singleton, Want Function use static method"**

It depends on what you want. Whenever you want the object state (e.g. Polymorphism like Null state instead of `null`, or default state), singleton is the appropriate choice for you whereas the static method use when you need function (Receive inputs then return an output).

I recommend for the singleton case, it should be always the same state after it is instantiated. It should neither be clonable, nor receive any value to set into (except static configuration from the file e.g. **properties** file in java).

P.S. The performance between these 2 are different in milliseconds, so focus on **Architecture** first.

Answer (score 1):

According to GoF’s book *Design Patterns*, chapter ‘Singleton’, class operations have the following drawbacks compared to singletons (bold emphasis mine):

> 5. *More flexible than class operations.* Another way to package singleton’s functionality is to use class operations (that is, static member functions in C++ or class methods in Smalltalk). But both of these language techniques make it **hard to change a design to allow more than one instance of a class.** Moreover, static member functions in C++ are never virtual, so **subclasses can’t override them polymorphically.**