# Android - save Object to SharedPreferences and get it anywhere in the app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, gson

In my app I have a custom `User` class which holds some regular data (name etc...). I need to save that object and get it anywhere and anytime in other pages of the app. I made a helper class `public final class GeneralMethods` with many methods which I use a lot (static, of course). 
 In order to save the data Im using `Gson` library. I made this method:

```
public static void saveData(Context con, String variable, String data)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
    prefs.edit().putString(variable, data).apply();
}
```

To save an object, I use this method as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String stringUser = gson.toJson(newUser);    
GeneralMethods.saveData(VerificationActivity.this,"userObject",stringUser);
```

To load the data back, I'm using this static method:

```
public static String getData(Context con, String variable, String defaultValue)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
    String data = prefs.getString(variable, defaultValue);
    return data;
}
```

I dont really know how to get the data back, this is what I've done so far:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String user="";
String value="";
user = GeneralMethods.getData(SplashScreenActivity.this,value,"userObject");
```

Im struggling with the `getData` method, how do I parse the data from `String` back to the `User` type?

EDIT
I tried the suggestions bellow and I always get `NULL`. Maybe I dont save the object in the right way?

EDIT2
It seems Im not generating the object correctly and therefore nothing is being saved. This is the user "Singleton" class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static User userInstance=null; //the only instance of the class
    private static String userName; //userName = the short phone number
    private User(){}

    public static User getInstance(){
        if(userInstance ==null){
            userInstance = new User();
        }
        return userInstance;
    }

    public static User getUserInstance() {
        return userInstance;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return this.userName;
    }

    public static void setUserName(String userName) {
        User.userName = userName;
    }

    public static void init(String _userName) {
        User.setUserName(_userName);
    }
}
```

This is how i setup the object with the relevant data (user name as the constructor parameter):

```
   User.init(name);
```

This is how i convert the object to a `String`:

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
    String stringUser = gson.toJson(User.getInstance());
GeneralMethods.saveData(VerificationActivity.this,"userObject",stringUser);
```

Comment: Bad idea to use serialization for data storing. Use something for storing data. Realm for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your existing User class with below

```
public class User implements Serializable
{

    private static User userInstance = null; // the only instance of the class
    private String userName; // userName = the short phone number
    private User(){}
    public static User getInstance()
    {
        if (userInstance == null)
        {
            userInstance = new User();
        }
        return userInstance;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String p_userName)
    {
        userName = p_userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "User [userName=" + getUserName() + "]";
    }
}
```

Initialize  User Name

```
User m_user = User.getInstance();
m_user.setUserName(name);
```

Convert the object to a String

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String stringUser = gson.toJson(m_user);
GeneralMethods.saveData(VerificationActivity.this,"userObject",stringUser);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked as expected. Why did you have to remove the private constructor of the 'User' class?

Comment: Why does it have to `implements Serializable` just to save in GSON?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to use *Dependency Injection* pattern.

I usually create `Preferences` class which exposes getters and setters to quickly read and save values to `SharedPreferences`.
I inject the same instance of `Preferences` anywhere in the code using [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) as Dependency Injector.

Why use *Singleton* object over `public static` helpers?

> If you have a helper class of utility functions that you're using directly, it creates a hidden dependency; you have no control over who can use it, or where. Injecting that same helper class via a stateless singleton instance lets you control where and how it's being used, and replace it / mock it / etc. when you need to.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2765109/870674).

Example of `Preferences` class:

```
@Singleton
public class Preferences {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final String NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED = "NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED";

    @Inject
    public Preferences(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 0);
    }

    public void setNotificationsEnabled(boolean enabled){
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED, enabled);
        edit.commit();           
    }

    public boolean isNotificationsEnabled(){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED, true);
    }
}
```

and how to use it in `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject
    NavigationController navigationController;

    @Inject
    Preferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedObjectGraph.getObjectGraph().inject(this);

        if(preferences.isNotificationsEnabled()){
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to just replace one line of code

```
user = GeneralMethods.getData(SplashScreenActivity.this,value,"userObject");
```

To

```
user = GeneralMethods.getData(SplashScreenActivity.this,"userObject",value);
```

Comment: I tried what you've suggested and it seems something else is broken. When I create a new user and save it, when I try to get the user's name, i get NULL. Maybe i dont save the object correctly?

Comment: Did you get string from "String stringUser = gson.toJson(newUser);"  this line I checked your code & working fine.

Comment: Apparently not, i get only `{ }`. Probably not creating the object correctly. Im using a Singleton as the base `User` class. I will update my question with the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the data back-

```
//Creating a shared preference
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
    MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getData(Context con, String variable)
{
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
String data = prefs.getString(variable, null);
return data;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = GeneralMethods.getData(SplashScreenActivity.this,"userObject");
if(json!=null){
  MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
}
```

Comment: What is `GeneralMethods`?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly, but i think you have switched the two fields in the getData method.

You have this method:

```
public static String getData(Context con, String variable, String defaultValue)
{....}
```

But you are sending in this:

```
user = GeneralMethods.getData(SplashScreenActivity.this,value,"userObject");
```

That means that your variable is this.value and your defaultValue is "userObject". I believe you want to have it the other way around

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

This will help you to create a class of shared preference and use it any where in any class.

1. **Create a class named as MySharedPreferences**

   ```
   public class MySharedPreferences
   {
    public static final String mySharedPrefrences = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
     private static MySharedPreferences instance;

   public static MySharedPreferences with(Context context) {
   if (instance == null) {
       instance = new MySharedPreferences(context);
   }
   return instance;
   }

   public MySharedPreferences(Context context)
   {
   sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(mySharedPrefrences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   }

   public static String  getUserId(String str_userid)
   {
   if (sharedPreferences!= null) {
       return sharedPreferences.getString(str_userid, "");
   }
   return "";
   }

   public void saveUserId(String str_userId_key,String str_userId_value)
   {
   editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.putString(str_userId_key,str_userId_value);
   editor.commit();
   }

   public void clearAllData(Context context)
   {
   sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(mySharedPrefrences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.clear().apply();
   }
   }
   ```
2. **And use this like**

   ```
   MySharedPreferences yourPrefrence =MySharedPreferences.with(getActivity());yourPrefrence.saveUserId("str_userId_key",et_title.getText().toString().trim());
   String value = yourPrefrence.getUserId("str_userId_key");
   ```